# Spring boot integration test Watch Service Struggles

Tags: java, spring-boot, watchservice

Hi Having a couple of issues in writing an integration test for a spring boot service which uses the Java watch service.

First off I require my Spring bean to run on start up, so have implemented the ApplicationRunner interface.  I then set my watch service to poll for events with the take() method.  This blocks until an event is received.  The issue I have is no matter what I do in my integration test, the test is never getting executed, as it seems to block on the watcher.take() method

```
@Component
public class MyClass implements ApplicationRunner {

private static Boolean shutdown;

private WatchService watcher;

@Value("${file.location}")
private String fileLocation;

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {

    Path myDir = Paths.get(fileLocation);

    try {
        watcher = myDir.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
        myDir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
        while(true) {
            WatchKey watchKey = watcher.take();
            List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watchKey.pollEvents();
            for (WatchEvent event : events) {
                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    //dosomething
                }
            }

            watchKey.reset();
        }
    }
```

}

My integration test class below it never seems to execute the first line of my test?  It just goes to my run method of my main class.  also is it possible to change the value of my fileLocation injected value in my integration test?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestIT {


@Test
public void testFileGetsPickedUpAndProcessed() throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("pickMe.txt").getFile());

    file.renameTo(new File("/tmp/pickMe.txt"));
    //some assertions

}
```

Answer (score 0):

watcher.take() is a blocking method. 
Be sure to run your code in another Thread to run your test.

I had the same issue for my application. This code works and handles creation/modification events:

```
while(true) {
    WatchKey watchKey = watcher.take();
    List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watchKey.pollEvents();
    for (WatchEvent event : events) {

        if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
             handleNewFileCreated(event);
        } else if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
             handleFileModified(event);
        }
    }

    watchKey.reset();

    // Wait a moment
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

And add a sleep, never let a "*while(true)*"

Regards

Comment: The sleep is not needed since `watcher.take()` blocks, so this is not a busy wait loop.